# Magento: Upgrade script is run before core installation is complete

Tags: magento, deployment, automation, installation, magento-1.7

I'm working on automating the deployment of a Magento (1.7.0.2 community) shop. In order to do that, I have a Git repository with the complete codebase, including all installed modules.

I run the command-line based installer (`install.php`) on deployment, against an empty database. But apparently the SQL update scripts of the modules are being run before the installer fully completes, which causes a problem:

There is a (custom) script that creates a new (adminhtml) user role, and it seems that this role is created before Magento's own `Administrators` role. That wouldn't be bad, but the initial admin user is created as being part of our *custom* role - not the Administrators! (I suspect the Installer simply uses something like `parent_id = 1` when creating the user, with `1` normally being the Administrators group, but in this case it's our custom one.)

So, my question is: How do I either keep the upgrade script from being executed while the installer is running (and have it run on the first page load instead), or tell the installer to run this upgrade script only *after* the initial user and roles setup is complete? Or do you see a completely different solution?

In case that's useful: This is what our upgrade script basically does:

```
<?php
$roleData = array(
        'role_name'   => 'My_Shiny_Role',
        'role_type'   => 'G',
);
$role = Mage::getModel('admin/role')->setData($roleData)->save();

$resources[0] = '__root__';
Mage::getModel("admin/rules")
    ->setRoleId($role->getId())
    ->setResources($resources)
    ->saveRel();
```

(It's not encapsulated in a class, simply plain PHP.)

Comment: Have you considered just importing a database created off of a fresh install of Magento then triggering a request to perform the upgrade, rather than trying to trigger the install on the other system?

Comment: No. This is not about moving an installation from A to B, this is about doing a fresh install. Think of it as being part of automated testing. Getting a possibly dirty database from somewhere else and using that as the starting point isn't particularly safe nor reproducible.

Comment: Of course if it's 'possibly dirty' this would be unsafe, but the same could be said of source code, I don't personally see a problem with keeping a fresh database.sql file in your repo. Importing this and triggering a request to upgrade is perfectly automate-able. That's what I have set-up on my local machine for testing modules etc, I can then easily drop the database hard reset the git repo and I'm good to start again. If you don't want to do it that way though, that's cool. I've noticed in the past that upgrades can be triggered concurrently. Could this be the issue you're encountering?

Comment: It might be easier to run the database update scripts *first*, via
    `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';`
    `Mage::app('admin');`
    `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates();`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a "Magento Way" to disable the database update function from executing, but you could do it in SQL via:

```
UPDATE
core_resource
SET 
version = CONCAT('9.', version),
data_version = CONCAT('9.', data_version);
```

and then reenable it with:

```
UPDATE
core_resource
SET 
version = SUBSTR(version, 3),
data_version = SUBSTR(data_version, 3);
```